# Regions in Delphi - is it possible to define them unfold by default?

Tags: delphi, ide, code-regions

Since Delphi 2005 Borland/CodeGear introduced the regions in the IDE. It is good idea but in some casses I want my regions to be unfolded by default in other folded. If there argument or options that will do the job? I'm using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ntodorov, you can turn off the code folding pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Check these links

- [Delphi Tips And Tricks: Turn Off Code Folding](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2007/07/delphi-tips-and-tricks-turn-off-code.html)
- [Keyboarding [Part 3] – Code Folding](http://tdelphihobbyist.blogspot.com/2007/07/keyboarding-part-3-code-folding.html)

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean code folding?  If so, the "project desktop" autosave option controls whether your current folding information is saved.  With the option on it will keep your code foldings set to how they were when you last used the project.